# How to filter username from harmful characters

Tags: php, html

i really need help from you guys !!
some of my friends are scamming on my website.
like typing username : %%#&^$%#

i just want code that delete Row if harmful characters is found.
if possible blocking users ip address.
:)

Comment: coz i dont want my site look dirty from characters

Comment: and i am afraid of being hack from sql injection

Comment: @BartoszZasada  thanks bt i want to delete those row from database if harmful characters

Comment: Use a regexp in a script, or `UPDATE table SET col = REPLACE(col, 'bad_character', '')` a few times.

Comment: this is my website : https://www.spickywolf.com , visit once :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/", $username))
  Die ($username." is not allowed username here!")
```

Comment: I hope I'll never have to use a website that communicates validation errors with `die`.

Comment: @diavolic thanks alot !! Am sure this code will work :) :)

Comment: if (!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/", $username)){ echo 'username without harmful character'; }else{ echo 'sorry'; }

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: People, if somebody trying to scam your script, using die for this user is preferable. No mercy for attackers